# Spring XD Using custom TCP serializer

Tags: java, spring, tcp, spring-xd

I extended `AbstractByteArraySerializer`and now I want to use this serializer like the rest of the available TCP serializers (LF, NULL, L1, ...).

I found the profiles in `tcp-encdec.xml` and registered my own profile:

```
...

<beans profile="use-custom">
    <bean id="CUSTOM"
        class="custom.tcp.serializer.ByteArrayCustomSerializer">
        <property name="maxMessageSize" value="${bufferSize}" />
    </bean>
</beans>

...
```

Spring uses `EncoderDecoderMixins.Encoding` to convert `Encoding` to a specific profile.

`EncoderDecoderMixins.Encoding` is an enum in a final class. Spring converts the `decoder` TCP property to a specific profile based on this enum. My CUSTOM serializer won't work since it isn't in the specified `Encodings`.

Is there a way to register a new `Encoding` or do I have to write a new Source module to use my serializer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you will need a custom source; we could probably add another enumeration, such as `CUSTOM`, where you provide the classname of the deserializer but that will need a change to the standard source.

A quick and dirty work-around would be to modify the source locally:

```
<int-ip:tcp-connection-factory id="connectionFactory"
    ...
    deserializer="myDeserializer"/>

<bean id="myDeserializer" class="foo.Deser" />
```

i.e. change the `${decoder}` placeholder to point to your bean.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!